# Matplotlib small data in linear scale, fontsize of exponent

Tags: python, matplotlib, formatting

When small data is plotted in matplotlib that has a *range* of less than an order of magnitude, I plot it on a linear scale. The plot then gets a label on the top right corner that indicates the exponent of the data, as in [the figure here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVLYS.png)

How can I make the fontsize of this top right corner exponent label larger?

Answer (score 0):

I think the size of the exponent may be related to the of the offset text which can be set by:

```
text_handle = ax.yaxis.get_offset_text()
text_handle.set_size(FontSize)
```

Let me know if this is working for you